# Show Outlook/Outlook Express popup before sending mail from vb6.0

Tags: vb6

I want to send email from VB6 application, but before sending i want to open outlook or outlook express popup/window with details filled from VB6 application.

I searched for this but it is possible with outlook email program.

So, how to send mail using the default email sending program and open email sending window before sending mail?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the mailto: API in Windows to do this, [see here](http://www.addressmunger.com/mailto_syntax_tutorial/) for examples on how to use the mailto API.

Your code might be something like:

```
Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Sub sendMail()
  ShellExecute 0, "open", "mailto:your@email.address?body=First Paragraph. %0A%0A Second paragraph. %0A%0A Third Paragraph etc.", 0, 0, 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, This code is working for both Outlook and Outlook Express but problem with attachment. It wont attach Attachment to email message.

Comment: @YoginiMane:  I haven't tried this myself, but there is an "attachment" parameter option to the mailto protocol, see comments here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: I tried this command but attachment is not working else it is working fine.